# Can't connect to remote ssh host using tramp on Windows

Tags: tramp, ssh

I have 2 operating systems: Windows XP and Linux Slackware.

In both operating systems I have the following text in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host beta
HostName <server IP>
User beta
Port 22
```

I can connect to ssh directly from shells, using the command: `ssh beta`. When I run `C-x C-f` and then `/ssh:beta:/home/beta` in Linux it works, the directory is opened in dired. On Windows it hangs. In `*Messages*` buffer I get the following:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for beta using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command `ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=no -e none beta && exit || exit'
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
Tramp: Opening connection for beta using ssh...failed
```

How to fix?

Comment: What is your ssh client? WinXP has none by default, so that's critical information. I'm slightly dubious that ControlMaster is available on Windows (it's certainly not if you're using Cygwin, last I knew). It used to be the case that you needed to use the `sshx` tramp method with a Cygwin-based ssh client, so try that? (or `plink` if you're using PuTTY).

Comment: @phils I have Cygwin ssh client on Windows: `OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013`. It works both from cygwin bash shell and from Windows command prompt.

Comment: There are known issues with Cygwin and Tramp when it comes to transfer the password. Does Emacs asks you for the remote password? If yes, please use ssh agent in order to avoid this.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus "Does Emacs asks you for the remote password?" - no

Comment: Then pls apply `(setq tramp-verbose 10)`. Rerun your test. There will be a Tramp debug buffer, which shall tell us the story.

Answer (score 4):

Try `sshx` command instead of `ssh` when opening with `C-x C-f`

For more, search `sshx` at https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/

Comment: This should be the answer. It's the only way I could TRAMP get working with ssh on Windows.

From the docs:
‘sshx’ is useful for MS Windows users when ‘ssh’ triggers an
error about allocating a pseudo tty. This happens due to missing
shell prompts that confuses TRAMP.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on :

- Windows 10
- Emacs found at https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/files/release/.
- cygwin64
- Putty.
- https://github.com/d5884/fakecygpty

The changes from the original `tramp-sh.el` is

- for cygwin, use fakecygpty with ssh and change the prompt to `##`
- for plink, remove `-ssh` option

I have also renamed these method with `w` to differentiate it.

```
(when (string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
  (add-to-list 'tramp-methods
               `("sshw"
                 (tramp-login-program        "fakecygpty ssh")
                 ;; ("%h") must be a single element, see `tramp-compute-multi-hops'.
                 (tramp-login-args           (("-l" "%u" "-o \"StrictHostKeyChecking=no\"") ("-P" "%p") ("-t")
                                              ("%h") ("\"")
                                              (,(format
                                                 "env 'TERM=%s' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=%s'"
                                                 tramp-terminal-type
                                                 "##"))
                                              ("/bin/sh") ("\"")))
                 (tramp-remote-shell         "/bin/sh")
                 (tramp-remote-shell-login   ("-l"))
                 (tramp-remote-shell-args    ("-c"))
                 (tramp-default-port         22))
               )

  (add-to-list 'tramp-methods
               `("plinkw"
                 (tramp-login-program        "plink")
                 ;; ("%h") must be a single element, see `tramp-compute-multi-hops'.
                 (tramp-login-args           (("-l" "%u") ("-P" "%p") ("-t")
                                              ("%h") ("\"")
                                              (,(format
                                                 "env 'TERM=%s' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=%s'"
                                                 tramp-terminal-type
                                                 "$"))
                                              ("/bin/sh") ("\"")))
                 (tramp-remote-shell         "/bin/sh")
                 (tramp-remote-shell-login   ("-l"))
                 (tramp-remote-shell-args    ("-c"))
                 (tramp-default-port         22))
               )
  )
```