# Tramp can't connect - cannot find ssh

Tags: tramp, ssh, path

I am trying to use Tramp, but it seems unable to execute the `ssh` command.

Here is the error from `*Messages*`:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for AWS2 using ssh...
Word wrapping enabled
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none AWS2’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
Tramp failed to connect.  If this happens repeatedly, try
    ‘M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
Tramp: Opening connection for AWS2 using ssh...failed
```

and this appears briefly in a pop-up buffer:

```
/bin/sh: 1: exec: ssh: not found
```

which makes me think it might be something to do with the `PATH` that Emacs is getting.

---

The contents of the auto-generated `tramp` file inside `~/.emacs.d/`, which I have deleted and was recreated:

```
;; -*- emacs-lisp -*- <20/07/16 14:53:07 /home/user/.emacs.d/tramp>
;; Tramp connection history.  Don't change this file.
;; You can delete it, forcing Tramp to reapply the checks.

(((tramp-file-name "ssh" nil nil "AWS2" nil nil nil)
  nil))
```

`AWS2` is a `Host` defined in `~/.ssh/config`, with other settings (`User`, `Identityfile`, `Port`, etc).

### More info:

- I have tried `tramp-cleanup-*-connections` (all variants thereof).
- Tried [instead using the `sshx:`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21890/cant-connect-to-remote-ssh-host-using-tramp-on-windows) command/prefix - same error.
- I can open a plain bash terminal and successfully connect using `ssh AWS2`.
- In other IDEs, I am also able to set up an ssh-based SFTP connection and that works fine.
- I have [set a simple prompt](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27410/cant-connect-with-tramp-tramp-file-name-handler-couldn-t-find-local-shell-prom) on the remote machine for "dumb" `$TERM` values.
- Tramp version: `2.3.5.26.3`
- Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2019-12-23`
- OS: `Ubuntu 16.04`
- Restarted my machine
- Looked for any clues that Tramp has been blocked on the remote machine (given other connection routes work), but didn't find anything.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45044/how-to-debug-hanging-tramp-connections) helps get more info?

Comment: Indeed. Set `tramp-verbose` to 6, and rerun your test. Check the traces for level `(6)` messages. If you don't have a clue, write to `tramp-devel@gnu.org` (SX is not intended to debug).

Comment: @NickD - I already had verbosity set to 10 to provide the output above. So there really isn't much to interpret as far as a stack trace goes. I'll send an email.

Comment: I would follow @MichaelAlbinus's advice: he knows!

Comment: In particular, the trace messages go to  a tramp debug buffer, not to `*Messages*`.